# How to select pandas row(s) which has attributes column value equals to any one of value from list

Tags: pandas

```
data = {
    "name": ["abc", "xyz", "pqr"],
    "attributes": [["attr2", "attr3"], ["attr2","attr4"], ["attr3", "attr1"] ]
}

df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data)
```

How do i filter rows which satisfies this condition:
select row if it's attributes column contains values any of "attr1" or "attr3"

expected output is:

```
    name      attributes
0  "abc"  ["attr2", "attr3"]
1  "pqr"  ["attr3", "attr1"]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get a boolean indexer,

```
>>> idx = df['attributes'].map(lambda l: any(s in l for s in ['attr1', 'attr3']))
>>> idx
0     True
1    False
2     True
Name: attributes, dtype: bool
```

Then

```
>>> df.loc[idx]
  name      attributes
0  abc  [attr2, attr3]
2  pqr  [attr3, attr1]
```

Whether you want to reset the index afterward is up to you.

Answer (score 2):

Using

```
df[pd.DataFrame(df.attributes.tolist()).isin(['attr1','attr3']).any(1)]
Out[295]: 
       attributes name
0  [attr2, attr3]  abc
2  [attr3, attr1]  pqr
```